# How to get the name of the select wallpaper

Tags: c#

How can I get the name of the current desktop wallpaper in Windows, using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @tanascius's answer, I came up with this code.

**Windows 7:**

```
var wpReg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Desktop\\General\\", false);
var wallpaperPath = wpReg.GetValue("WallpaperSource").ToString();
wpReg.Close();
```

**Windows XP:**

```
var wpReg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false);
var wallpaperPath = wpReg.GetValue("WallPaper").ToString();
wpReg.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like [this](http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/gets-the-current-wallpaper-path-SID605.aspx)?

```
var wpReg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey( "Control Panel\\Desktop", false );
var wallpaperPath = wpReg.GetValue( "WallPaper" ).ToString();
wpReg.Close();
```

From the path you can extract the filename ...

Comment: How can i do it in a mac os ?? its possible with c# our java?